# MODX Access page content from snipet

Tags: modx-revolution, chunks

I have a parent page where I want to load through a chunk the content of several child pages just like in a blog roll:

Child1 content is text : Text for page Child 1

Child2 content is text : Text for page Child 2

Child3 content is text : Text for page Child 3

What I don't know is how to access the content of Child1, Child2, Child3 pages in the chunk. I tried like this `[[~id_of_each_page]]` but it didn't show anything.

Any thoughts on this, guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer : I should call these snipets from the parent page :

```
[[getResourceField? &id=`6` &field=`content`]]
[[getResourceField? &id=`7` &field=`content`]]
[[getResourceField? &id=`8` &field=`content`]]
```

Obviously you have to get first getResourceField from extras.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but `getResources` (the extra) is made for this. You can use it to specify what children, or what parents to list content from. It is also very customizable so you can include template-variables or anything you like, order, limit and so on.